# How to Invoke a function in a List in C#

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I'm fairly new to C# and trying to figure out how to invoke a function from a list. I thought that List would do the job I need it to. I can get my functions into the list, but I can't seem to actually invoke them.

First I tried this:

```
List<Action> randEvent = new List<Action>();

 void Test()
    {
        randEvent.Add(Test2);
        Invoke(randEvent(0), 0f);
    }

    void Test2()
    {
        print("This is a test of the random event system");
    }
```

Then this

```
   List<Action> randEvent = new List<Action>();

   void Test()
    {
        randEvent.Add(Test2);
        randEvent(0);
    }

    void Test2()
    {
        print("This is a test of the random event system");
    }
```

But neither works. What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible? The reason I want to do it this way is basically that I have 100 functions that I want my program to chose through at random when I call another function.

Any solution appreciated, though keep in mind I'm very new to C# and code in general still. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is `randEvent` defined?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Sorry, missed that line in my copy Plutonix, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: As problem descriptions go, "But neither works" is really very poor. The compiler/runtime/debugger all offer very useful information (error messages, stack traces etc) about the nature of the "not-working-ness" which you should present with your question. Not doing so might be viewed as lazy.

Comment: I didn't think it would be necessary or even helpful as the "not working" is purely misuse of syntax. The errors wouldn't be useful to anyone reading this question.

Comment: @Rathlord Sure they would. For instance, you'll have been given an indication of where the error is within the few hundred characters of code that you presented. That's useful information to someone trying to help you. More importantly, by taking the time to state all the facts you might gain insight into your own problem. Writing an SO question is a form of "[talking to the duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)".

Comment: I understand where you're coming from, but in this specific example it very much isn't that. The compiler error wouldn't have helped anyone. It's incorrect syntax and I already knew that, I just didn't know what the correct was. I pointed out exactly where the error was- invoking the function from the array. There's no possible situation with this situation where it could be useful. Again, I agree with you in general but in this specific case it couldn't have possibly helped anyone. I appreciate what you're trying to do, but it's not helpful.

Comment: The text of the compiler error /syntax error would help a future user who is googling for that exact error message... Ultimately landing them here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C#/.NET, different method signatures have different delegate types that represent them. `Action` represents functions that take no arguments and return no value, like `void Foo()`.  If the functions you want to represent take a `float` parameter and return nothing, you would need to use `Action<float>`. Functions with return values are represented with the `Func` family of types (`Func<T>`, `Func<T1, T2>`...).

You can only put one kind of delegate in a `List<T>`, so you can't mix `Action`s and `Action<float>`s.

To get an item out of a list in C#, use `[n]`.  Like

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();
actions.Add(Foo);
Action a = actions[0];
```

To invoke a delegate instance in C#, call the `Invoke` method on it, or just use `()` which is shorthand for calling `Invoke`.  For `Action`, `Invoke` takes 0 parameters, for `Action<T>` it takes a single `T` parameter, etc.

So for your whole example:

```
List<Action> actions = new List<Action>();

void Test()
{
    actions.Add(PrintStuff);
    actions[0]();
    //or
    actions[0].Invoke();
    //or
    foreach (var a in actions) a();
}

void PrintStuff()
{
    print("This is a test of the random event system");
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, all I had to do was change the line to:

randEvent[0]();

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could declare sort of a list of `Action` and each object will point to a specific method. Example;

```
IList<Action> actionList = new List<Action>();
actionList.Add(() => Test2());
```

Then you can loop through the list and `Invoke` each method.

```
foreach(var method in actionList)
{
    method.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: You don't need to do `Add( () => Test2() )`, you can just do `Add( Test2 )`. The lambda just adds a useless layer of indrection and the performance overhead of a closure.

Comment: I'm looking to invoke them randomly, which is why I'm doing it this way. So I need a way to call them one at a time, based on a random number I'm inputting. Not looking to do it all at once nor in order. Thanks for the reply, though.

Comment: @Rathlord once you have a generated index, you can pass that value in the list to get the method. `actionList[3].Invoke();` *assuming 3 is a random number*

Comment: Thanks for all the help- found a simpler solution (for my head to wrap around, at least), but I really appreciate the time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `randEvent` is a `List<EventHandler>` or `List<Action<Int32>>`.

Use `Delegate.Invoke( args )` (as `EventHandler` and `Action<T>` are both `Delegate` sub-types).

```
randEvent[0].Invoke( 123 );
```

In C#, you can use `()` on a `Delegate` directly too:

```
randEvent[0]( 123 );
```